# Why i am getting result from "else if" even though "if" condition is true

Tags: javascript, json, object, google-api

Google reverse geocoding gives me result like this

```
results: [
{address_components: [
{long_name: "New York",
short_name: "NY",
types: ["neighborhood"]},]

{address_components: [
{long_name: "London",
short_name: "LN",
types: ["sublocality_level_1"]},]}]
```

here is code for getting result for long name of "neighborhood":

```
for (i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
for (var acd = 0; acd < response.results[i].address_components.length; acd++) {
var fff =  response.results[i].address_components[acd];
var storableLocation;
if(fff.types.includes("neighborhood")) {
storableLocation = fff.long_name;
}else if (fff.types.includes("sublocality_level_1")){
storableLocation = fff.long_name;}}}

console.log(storableLocation) gives result - London.
```

Why it shows result for London if first condition is true? it should have consoled New York or i am mistaken ?

Comment: What are `i` and `acd`?

Comment: You need to add a more complete example. From this it looks like you are assigning the same value to `storableLocation` regardless which branch it takes.

Comment: `i` obviously equals `1` ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler I suspect `i` is a loop variable for a loop we don't see.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that loop might be `for(i=1; i < response.results.length; i++)`... because if it were properly initialized to index `0`, it would (most likely) be the expected result.

Comment: @MartinZeitler if the loop starts at 0, and ends before `response.results.length` the last iteration will have `i = 1` and `storableLocation` will be 'london'. Because the `storableLocation = fff.long_name` regardless of the `if`.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {for (var acd = 0; acd < response.results[i].address_components.length; acd++), i and acd are variables for loop

Comment: @Tod, then you should show the loop. You're asking people to guess what's going on. Make a runnable snippet that shows the problem and you'll get *much* better responses.

Answer (score 0):

Because `console.log(storableLocation)` is outside of both loops, you are seeing the second value that was assigned to the `var storableLocation`. You are not seeing the first value assigned to the variable because by the time you `console.log`, the loops already finished and reassigned `storableLocation` to London in the else if statement.

Instead, you should do the following:

```
var results = [ {address_components: [
{long_name: "New York",
short_name: "NY",
types: ["neighborhood"]}]},

{address_components: [
{long_name: "London",
short_name: "LN",
types: ["sublocality_level_1"]}]}]

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   var storableLocation;
   loop2:
   for (var acd = 0; acd < results[i].address_components.length; acd++) {
       var fff =  results[i].address_components[acd];
       if(fff.types.includes("neighborhood")) {
          storableLocation = fff.long_name;
          console.log(storableLocation)
          break loop1;
       }
       else if (fff.types.includes("sublocality_level_1")){
          storableLocation = fff.long_name;
       }
   }
}
```